# Как образуются наречия?

Tags: словообразование

Как образовались наречия "вприпрыжку, вдогонку, враскачку" -  от глагола или от отглагольного существительного? Скорее всего, здесь применяется один и тот же способ образования слов, но вот в одном из словарей указывается: догонять - вдогонку, припрыжка - вприпрыжку.

Также "брод - вброд" или "брести - бредет - вброд"?

Кажется, что все эти наречия по значению мотивированы глаголами.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это один способ - приставочно-суффиксальный.

Прыгать-прыгнуть - припрыгнуть-припрыжка-вприпрыжку-прист-суфф.

Гнать-догнать-догонять-вдогонку- прист-суфф

Качать-раскачать-раскачка-враскачку-прист-суфф

Брести-бродить - брод - вброд-приставочный, но некоторые учёные усматривают приставочно-суффиксальный: якобы нулевое окончание превращается в нулевой суффикс.

Comment: А зачем вообще нужно промежуточное отглагольное прилагательное (неважно, существует оно или нет)?  И какой вид глагола нужно использовать? Мне кажется так: раскачиваться - враскачку (раскачиваясь), догонять - вдогонку (догоняя), припрыгивать - вприпрыжку (припрыгивая). Наречия по смыслу и грамматическому значению  как бы соотносятся с деепричастиями несовершенного вида  (второе действие как признак основного действия).

Comment: Не поняла, о каких отглагольных прилагательных речь. От них могут образовываться только наречия на - о: путаный ответ - говорить путано; бешеный ритм - бешено мчаться.

Comment: Людмила, извините, ошибка: имелись в виду отглагольные существительные припрыжка, раскачка. Какой  смысл включать их в словообразовательную цепочку?

Comment: А как же без них? Будет пропуск в цепочке, не может же сразу 2 суффикса присоединиться - к- и -у-: при/прыг/ива/ть-в/при/прыж/к/у.Суффикс -к- мы берём от сущ."припрыжка", а уж потом с помощью в-+-у вприпрыжку

Comment: А догонять - вдогонку, здесь же два суффикса присоединяются.

Comment: _Sergey: А догонять - вдогонку, здесь же два суффикса присоединяются._ === Кто-то из лингвистов считает, что два, кто-то -- что один ("-ку").

Comment: Видимо, когда-то было сущ. догонка, (как припрыжка и раскачка) потом оно исчезло, в совр. языке его нет, вставлять в цепочку несуществующее слово  нелогично, потому здесь получается цепочка с пропуском.